# input string was not in a correct format textbox vb visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net

[image: image here]

i have no idea what to do anymore, I'm just following a tutorial I made sure I typed it in correctly? but it kept on saying input string was not in a correct format, I was trying to total the drinks pls help I'd already restarted this project for the third time

Comment: And why exactly would you think that you could convert an empty string to a number? If you expect to convert input to a number then don't you think you ought to provide some input?

Comment: In future, please don't post just a picture of your code. If a picture adds some value then provide it but ALWAYS post the code as text, formatted as code. Please take the site tour that you ignored when prompted and spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a good question.

Comment: Use `Double.TryParse` and tell the user that he should enter something.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, there's no need to set it to zero if `TryParse` returns `False` because the output parameter will already be set to zero in that case. You can just ignore the return value and just use the output regardless. That said, that's not going to distinguish between and empty field, which may well be valid, and a field with nonnumeric input, which is not valid. A real app would handle that in the `Validating` event handler but a beginner teaching project won't be doing that.

Comment: For the record, there's no need to declare a variable on one line and initialise it on another. They can and should be done on the same line.

Comment: I put in a symbol on the tx1 that time and it showed an error, thought putting in a character is wrong so I emptied it, I put 0 and it's working now thank you very much and sorry for asking a very dumb question I'm still not very used to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to convert an empty String to a Double, which cannot happen. You should either:

1. Replace your TextBox controls with NumericUpDown controls ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown))
2. Replace Convert.ToDouble with Double.TryParse ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse))

Here is an example using the latter:

```vb
Dim cider_soda As Double
If (Not Double.TryParse(tx1.Text, cider_soda)) Then
    MessageBox.Show("The value in tx1 cannot be converted to a Double.")
End If
```

If you wanted to make a specific distinction if the text is empty, use the String.IsNullOrWhitespace ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace)):

```vb
Dim cider_soda As Double
If (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(tx1.Text)) Then
    MessageBox.Show("The value in tx1 cannot be empty.")
ElseIf (Not Double.TryParse(tx1.Text, cider_soda)) Then
    MessageBox.Show("The value in tx1 cannot be converted to a Double.")
End If
```